# html5 file uploader uploads the same file content to the server

Tags: javascript, filereader

I use this script http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/ to show progress of a file upload etc. It works great except that moment if you drag and drop a few files simultaneously it will creates files with different names but content of those files will be the same. So that script just pass content of the first loaded file in all cases. How to fix this?

Comment: I have already fixed that. I changed reader to reader[file.name] so it uses different instances and sends correct content

Comment: You should copy the relevant code into your question. It sounds like a reference to an object is being reused unintentionally.